# Change color of icons in status bar - Windows 10 Mobile UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I have an uwp app published in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I want change color of icons in status bar.
I know change color of status bar background, but I can how change color of icons in status bar in Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
    if (statusBar != null)
        statusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
}
```

You'd also need to add reference to *Windows Mobile Extensions* into your project:
[image]